# Error encountered during installation of VS2019

Tags: visual-studio

windows version：windows server 2019 Standard

I tried to install by double-clicking install.exe   and  the result is

> The application cannot find one of its required files, possibly because it was unable to create it in the folder. Please make sure that the folder in which this application was downloaded is accessible and not read-only.

[image]

I have tried installing the offline version, but the error still persists.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you check the content of the folder you tried to install into, what do you see? No files at all? One file? Many files? No files but a folder? Many folders? Empty folders? What is the remaining free space on the drive with that folder? Is the folder write protected? What kind of privileges are you using while installing? User? Admin?